# Regular expression for extracting a series of hex numbers from a file

Tags: regex, perl

I am examining an object dump of a file and I want to figure out all the possible addresses.

The approach I am using involves using perl and regex to extract all words

The format of the object file is like this

```
00000000000044444 <function>
    44448: 48 ca             add ....
    4444c: 48 ca 55          call ....
    44450: 48 ca 8d 55       jmp..
```

I am trying to extract `48 ca 48 ca 55 48 ca 8d 55`

Currently, i thought that the regex `/(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\s)/g` would help however, that only extracts every other, i.e`48, 8d, 55`, as it parse `48` and then it cant parse `ca` because the previous space character has already been consumed (at least that is my understanding)

`/(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\s)|([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\s)/g` but that parses things it shouldnt like an `add instruction` `dd`

Any help as to how I can only extract these pairs of numbers deliminated by a space?

Edit: I updated a more realistic format of the file.

Thank you

Comment: Are these existing object dumps or are you running `objdump` and then wanting to analyze them?  Is there some flag to `objdump` that could maybe give you more machine-readable format?

Comment: These are dumps from running objdump. I am not sure if there is such a flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `\s`, you just want the word boundary `\b`.

```
while (<DATA>) {
    my @nums = m/\b([[:xdigit:]]{2})\b/g;
    print "@nums\n";
}

__DATA__
00000000000044444 <function>
    44448: 48 ca 8d 55
    4444c: 48 ca 8d 55
    44450: 48 ca 8d 55
```

---

**Update**

Given, you made your data more complicated with instructions after the hex codes, I'd lean toward making your regex more restrictive like so;

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^\s+\w+:((?:\s[[:xdigit:]]{2})+)\b/) {
        my @nums = split ' ', $1;
        print "@nums\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
00000000000044444 <function>
    44448: 48 ca             add ....
    4444c: 48 ca 55          call ....
    44450: 48 ca 8d 55       jmp..
```

Outputs:

```
48 ca
48 ca 55
48 ca 8d 55
```

Comment: I should have just said that I'm just examining file generated by objdump. your initial answer seems to work well. Is there something the more restrictive regex captures that the first one doesn't?

Comment: The other way around.  The more restrictive regex avoids the possibility of ever capturing anything in the add,call,jump area.  Honestly, I'd be tempted to just use a `substr` and then `split`.

Comment: Don't use `[0-9a-f]`! What if the characters are upper case? What if the file is in a different language. Perl has the class `[[:xdigit:]]` which represents any hexadecimal digit: Upper or lowercase. Latin or non-latin. See the [Perl Regular Expression Reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html). Remember, we are no longer in an ASCII world.

Comment: @DavidW. *nod*.  An earlier version of my code used that character class, but it got copied over on edit.  I doubt that's a bang ! worthy warning in this instance since he's parsing the output to a specific app, but it's a worthwhile habit to get in regardless.  Btw, feel free to just edit next time.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this example that uses your regex in positive lookahead to perform overlapping matching:

```
$\ = $/;
while(<DATA>){
    print for m/(?=\s([0-9a-f][0-9a-f])\s)/g;
}

__DATA__
00000000000044444 <function>
    44448: 48 ca 8d 55
    4444c: 48 ca 8d 55
    44450: 48 ca 8d 55
```

Comment: I am very new to perl, what does $\ = $/ 

Currently I have

foreach $line (<INFO>)  {   
         
    my @matches = $line =~ /(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f])/g;

}

Comment: `$\ = $/` will add a `\n` after every printing. from code. If you can just copy the regex from my example into your code, it should work. Try it!

Comment: ok, it seems to work. looks like I will have to look more into this positive lookahead. so it seems that $\ = $/; isn't relevant to this. it seems that ?= seems to be the key.

Comment: @bubbles Or don't worry about lookahead and overlapping, by using a word boundary `\b` instead of an explicit `\s`.

Comment: @Miller word boundary will pick match from input like `10.10.10.10`

Comment: @Miller and nothing. Otherwise your suggested `\b` will be much faster than lookahead. Lookahead is always slower.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(([0-9a-f]{2}\s){3}[0-9a-f]{2})$
```

`[0-9a-f]{2}` is a pair of hex digits.

Group those with a space three times, and then look for another pair of hex digits after that.

The `$` anchors it to the end of the line.

Comment: Going to look into those. I should have mentioned that it may or may not be always the same amount of digits per line

Comment: Well, if you always know that the hex digit pair will be preceded by a space, you can do `\s[0-9a-f]{2}`.

Comment: yes that is true but in that example, it would also parse 44 3 times from 444**

Comment: What you can do is do this in two steps per line.  First strip off the leading address (`[0-9a-f]+:`), and then analyze the hex digits that follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
while(<DATA>) {
    print m/(?:(?<=:)|\G)( [a-f0-9]{2})(?=\s)/g;
}


__DATA__
00000000000044444 <function>
    44448: 48 ca             add ....
    4444c: 48 ca 55          call ....
    44450: 48 ca 8d 55       jmp..
```

The pattern is build to force byte to be consecutive with `\G` or to be preceded with `:`. *(If it doesn't suffice you can add `[0-9a-f]{5}` before the `:`)*

Comment: I like this solution.  Don't find that many situations where `\G` is all that useful, but this is one.

Comment: Thanks, the main interest is to add more constraint. `\G` is not always easy to master, and once you master it, you don't think to use it!